# Why on adding custom label to Y-Axis in MSChart all other non-custom labels disappear?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I trying to add custom label in Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.
Here is my code.

```
axisXData = new string[] { "05.06.2016", "06.06.2016"};    
axisYDataHigh = new double[] { 1.1364, 1.1372};
axisYDataOpen = new double[] { 1.1349, 1.1356};
axisYDataLow = new double[] { 1.1332, 1.1345};
axisYDataClose = new double[] { 1.1351, 1.1351};
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(axisXData, axisYDataHigh,axisYDataLow, axisYDataOpen, axisYDataClose);
```

I got nice chart with showed labels in YAxis. But when I tryed add custom label with:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(1.1334, 1,1366, "1.135");
```

all other labels disappeared and only custom label showed.
How to make non-custom labels not disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update (*) :**

`CustomLabels` can be displayed in several rows.

Normal `Labels` will only display in row 0.

For this default row the rule is: It is either or: Either regular `Labels` or `CustomLabels`. No way to combine them, unfortunately.

[MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456628%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Labeling Axes Using Custom Labels
>
> Use custom labels to provide custom text for axes. Custom labels are
>   implemented using the CustomLabels collection property. **If you use
>   custom labels, the chart area does not display axis labels from data
>   points.**

(*) **But**, as Tanner points out, `CustomLabels` can be combined on the same `Axis` if you move them to a row > 0 by setting their `RowIndex` property.

**Note**:  they still can't be combined with normal `Labels` on the same line.

Comment: Thank you, I really didn't find this information while was in search.

Comment: You can combine them using the RowIndex property above 0.  "The RowIndex property specifies on which row the custom label is displayed. If a custom label is used in the first label row, the chart area does not display any labels from the axis scale. The only labels permitted in the second row and beyond are custom labels."

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out. I have updated the answer.